# DataTable Odd Behavior when Deleting Data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I'm adding and deleting row on datatable via ajax.. when I delete data on the datatable and call the `additional_info_datatable.ajax.reload()` it gives me errors.

here's the error:
[image]

Here's my code:

**PHP**

```
public function ajax_call_additional_info(){

        $result = $this->main_m->get_all_where('additional_info', array('is_deleted' => 0));

        $data = array();

        if(!empty($result)){
        foreach($result as $row){
            array_push($data, 
                    array(
                        'id' => $row['additional_info_id'], 
                        'description' => $row['description'], 
                        'action' => "<button type='button' data-url='".site_url(array('events','soft_delete_additional_info'))."' data-name='".$row['description']."' data-id='".$row['additional_info_id']."' class='btn btn-danger delete_additional_info'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-trash'></i></button>"
                        ));
        }

            echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array("draw" => 0, "recordsTotal" => 0, "recordsFiltered" => 0, "data" => array()));
        }
    }

    public function soft_delete_additional_info(){
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');

    $check_if_exist = $this->main_m->get_where('additional_info', array('additional_info_id' => $id));
    if(!empty($check_if_exist)){
        $this->main_m->update_data('additional_info', array('is_deleted' => 1), 'additional_info_id', $id);
        // $newdata = array(
        //         'type'  => 'success',
        //         'message'     => $name."'s successfully deleted!"
        // );
        // $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

        $message = array('type' => 'alert-success', 'message' => $name."'s successfully deleted!");

        echo json_encode($message);
        // echo site_url(array("events", "hotel_groupings", $check_if_exist['event_id']));
        // echo 1;
    }

}
```

**JQUERY**

**INITIALIZE DATATABLE:**

```
var additional_info = $("#additional_info_table");
    var additional_info_datatable = additional_info.DataTable({ 
        "ajax": additional_info.data('url'),
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "description" },
            { "data": "action" },
        ],
        "autoWidth": false,
        // scrollX: true,
        keys: true,
        // iDisplayLength: 10,
        // "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
            // buttons: []
      });
```

**DELETE CODE**

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_additional_info', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $url = $this.data('url');
        var $id = $this.data('id');
        var $name = $this.data('name');
        var $csrf_token = $("#csrf_token").val();

        bootbox.confirm({
            title: "Delete Data",
            message: "Do you want to delete <strong>"+$name+"</strong>? This process is irreversible.",
            buttons: {
                cancel: {
                    label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel'
                },
                confirm: {
                    label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Confirm'
                }
            },
            callback: function (result) {
                // console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);
                if(result){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:$url,
                        type:'post',
                        data:{id : $id, name: $name, csrf_test_name : $csrf_token},
                        dataType:'json',
                        success:function(data){
                            // console.log(data);
                            $(".alert").css("display","block");
                            $(".alert").addClass(data['type']);
                            $("#additional_info_message").html(data['message']);

                            additional_info_datatable.ajax.reload();

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: As the error shows, you need to find why these propertise is not defind. The code you show, have nothing to do with these the error. You need to check the page code, and debug the error in your browser console.

Comment: @KrisRoofe I see... I'm really not well verse with datatable... but thanks for your advice..